# Android 2.1 data usage tracking

Tags: android

I am working on an app in which I need to show the phone data usage and in [Android 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo) (Froyo) we have API "TrafficStats" for byte sent/recieved (Data usage), but it is not supported by 2.1 and I need to track data usage from version 2.1 itself.

Is there a way to track data usage of phone for Android version 2.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app [3g watchdog](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog&hl=en) should do what you ask.

Comment: Hi Graham I am working on a app where I have to read the phone data usage.

Comment: Apologies have you checked this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html you would need to create a service to monitor data usage and store the results on an ongoing basis.

Comment: Thanks Graham I will check the connectivityManager

Answer (score 1):

The app [My data manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm&hl=en) works out pretty well.